# Variables are being used?

Tags: java, variables

I have seen some threads on this same issue, so I greatly apologize if I missed reading over something but this issue is really annoying me. So I have this code here:

```
int megaBytes = 0;
int megaByteSpeed = 0;
int totalSeconds = 0;
int secondsRemainder = 0;
int hours = 0;
int minutes = 0;
int seconds = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and

```
if (megaBytes < 1000)
    {
        totalSeconds = megaBytes / megaByteSpeed;
        hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
        secondsRemainder = totalSeconds % 3600;
        minutes = secondsRemainder / seconds;
        seconds = minutes % 60;
    }
```

I understand that my coding may quite faulty, but I am new to Java and I'm starting to get a bit flustered.
The error I'm getting is saying that the variables; `megaByteSpeed`, `totalSeconds`, and `secondsRemainder` are not being used. Which clearly in the mathematical portion they are. Does anyone know why this would be happening? It's causing my project to stop mid run.

Thanks for any information,
Scuire.

entire code:

```
public class Ch03_ex3_DownloadTime {
  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Download Time Estimator!");
    System.out.println();

    int megaBytes = 0;
    int megaByteSpeed = 0;
    int totalSeconds = 0;
    int secondsRemainder = 0;
    int hours = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (megaBytes != 1000)
    {
      System.out.print("Enter download size: ");
      megaBytes = sc.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Enter download speed: ");
      megaByteSpeed = sc.nextInt();

      if (megaBytes < 1000)
      {
        totalSeconds = megaBytes / megaByteSpeed;
        hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
        secondsRemainder = totalSeconds % 3600;
        minutes = secondsRemainder / seconds;
        seconds = minutes % 60;
      }
      String message = "\n" 
                   +  "This download will take approximately " + hours + "hours" + minutes + "minutes and " + seconds + "seconds";
      System.out.println(message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What language is this, and why haven't you tagged it as such? Are you sure that "and" is correct syntax, or should it not have been code? How on Earth is a *warning* stopping your program?!

Comment: I recommend you post the whole code, for two reasons: it doesn't seem that those variables are *not* being used and most definitely that wouldn't crash your program. Especially in Java.

Comment: These are two separate pieces of code by the way, I thought it would have been over-kill to post my entire program.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use this website correctly quite yet. It's Java.

Comment: It's very hard for us to help if you can't give us more information. For your knowledge unused variables would not stop a program from running. You will only see warning in your IDE. Try-catch your code and debug your program to see where actually it stops.

Comment: Your IDE maybe giving you that warning, but mine is not. What version of Java and does your code actually work?

Comment: It's updated with the entire code that I have now. From further reading I'm seeing that it's not crashing the program, but in red letters is reading:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
 at ch03_ex3_downloadtime.Ch03_ex3_DownloadTime.main(Ch03_ex3_DownloadTime.java:47)
Java Result: 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me give you a tip: follow the sites instructions on how to post code.

Now, from what I can get out of your code I see that you are dividing by 0 
here:

```
    minutes = secondsRemainder / seconds;
```

here's the part you need to change in order to stop your loop

```
    boolean quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter download size: ");
        megaBytes = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter download speed: ");
        megaByteSpeed = sc.nextInt();

    if (megaBytes < 1000)
        {
            totalSeconds = megaBytes / megaByteSpeed;
            hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
            secondsRemainder = totalSeconds % 3600;
            minutes = secondsRemainder / seconds;
            seconds = minutes % 60;

        }
        String message = "\n" 
                       +  "This download will take approximately " + hours + "hours" + minutes + "minutes and " + seconds + "seconds";
        System.out.println(message);

        System.out.println("Do you want to continue 1= yes 0 = no");
        int ans  = 0;
        ans = sc.nextInt();
        if(ans ==0){
            quit = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have fixed the code, I no longer get the mathematical error, but it's just looping forever; asking me for the size, then the speed, then the size, then the speed, and so on. Do I need some other type of code in order to get it to run mathematics and to write out the answers?

Comment: the problem lies in your while statement, you are using this

       while(x<100)

i recomend you use a boolean value in your while so you can change it in the end like this

     while(!quit)

and after you run your math you ask the user if he wants to continue or not

Comment: Where exactly is it wrong?
Edit: I just saw the rest of your message.

Comment: Thank you for this information, but it has not fixed my looping issue. Would you, by looking at my code, be able to see why it won't continue through the code?

Comment: My entire code is as seen above, as my question. Only now, rather than the 'while' loop it's a boolean Y or N.

Comment: Demetrio, I actually found that it was just a misplaced bracket. Thank you for your help though. I would upvote it, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: that's cool just accept the answer then, glad I could help :)